# Redirected Urls in WebChromeClient

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In my app I want to display the urls in the webview which has another redirected urls and based on the redirected urls I Have to take some decision and also I need to show the updateting progress where according to me WebChrome Client is the best choice.
So,is it possible to get the redirected urls in the web chrome client?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function in your MainActivity;

```
rivate class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:") || url.startsWith("https://youtu.be/") {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        else {
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The url.startsWith while controle if you url starts with that. If yes it will open it in the specified app for that. So you can see I have add this:

> url.startsWith("https://youtu.be/")

so the link will be opened in the youtube app.

If you have anymore question just ask.